# Playing .bin video file runs slow. How can I make its execution faster?

Tags: image, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

My code is as follows:

```
image_name = filename    
f_uyvy = open(image_name, "rb")
image_out = array.array('B')
image_out = Image.new("RGB", (width, height),"rgb(85%,85%,85%)")
pix = image_out.load()
#YUV is converted into RGB and stored into numpy
    video = np.array(image_out) 
    cv2.imshow('video', video)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        exit()
print "File Ended"
```

It is working, but slowly. How can I show frames faster?

Comment: It is reading the .bin file also showing it but ,it is very slow need help to make execution fast so that it should look like playing a video in a video player.

Comment: I tried the above implementation with numpy but still it's slow only...and i tested for showing only only 1 channel value i.e.B-channel of RGB..
Need help to make execution faster...

Comment: Size of my .bin file is 7.5GB